# Doesn't Jacobi formula immediately follow from the chain rule

Tags: matrices, inner-products, chain-rule

It's easy to see that the derivative of $detA$ is $adj(A)^T$ applied to $A(t)$ we have $adj(A(t))^T$ and the derivative of $A(t)$ is simply $A'(t)$.

Now "multiplying" all this together with inner product ($tr$) gives $tr(adj(A)A'(t))$ which is what was desired.

I haven't seen this proof so far so I'm wondering if it's correct and possibly why it's not used. Is it because inner product isn't unique? Is the chain rule correct in those cases?

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't seem to make much sense, at least not as it's written now. The derivative of $\det A(t)$ is a *scalar*, but you're saying that it's easy to see that it equals something which is clearly a *matrix*...?!? Except that you then immediately change your mind and say that we should take the trace to magically make it work somehow. That's not proof of anything, it's just you pulling a formula out of a hat. Perhaps you could begin by trying to be more specific about what exactly the details regarding that “easy to see” part are?

Comment: @HansLundmark The derivative of $det A$ is a function from $R^{n\times n}$ to $R^{n\times n}$ and it's given by $adj(A)^T$ the derivative of $A(t)$ is $R$ to $R^{n\times n}$ given by differentiating every term on $t$, now by the chain rule the derivative is supposed to be $det'(A(t))*A'(t)$ given that if we use matrix multiplication this is a matrix it makes sense to consider a scalar product (inner product) the same way you'd for example $f(x,y) = xy, g(x)=(x,x)$ then $f(g(x)) = x^2$ and $f'(x,y) = (y,x)$ and $g'(x)=(1,1)$ then $f'(g(x))=(x,x)$ and finally $f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x) = x+x=2x$

Comment: @HansLundmark as for why the derivative of $det A$ is given by $adj A$ is simply that looking at the variable $a_{ij}$ and by Laplace expansion $det A = a_{ij}(-1)^{i+j}C_{ij}+\cdots$ so partial derivative at $a_{ij}$ is $(-1)^{i+j}C_{ij}$ so the resulting total derivative is $adj(A)^T$

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you meant the derivative of $\det A$ with respect to $t$ instead of $A$... Now it's starting to make more sense, but since we have $$\det \colon \mathbf{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbf{R},$$ surely the differential at the point $A \in \mathbf{R}^{n \times n}$ is a map $$d(\det)|_A \colon T_A \mathbf{R}^{n \times n} \to T_{\det A} \mathbf{R},$$ or, with the usual identifications, $$d(\det)|_A \colon \mathbf{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbf{R},$$ so here too the result is a scalar, not a matrix.

Comment: So $d(\det)|_A(B) = (\operatorname{adj} A)^T B$ can't possibly be quite the right formula.

Comment: @HansLundmark I thought of the Jacobian of det instead of the total derivative, I took it as $1\times n \times n$ matrix and just took it as a $n \times n$ matrix, the partial derivative of det at $A_{ij}$ variable is $(adj A)_{ji}$, and the $n \times n \times 1$ as a $n \times n$ matrix and I've basically bridged the gap with the inner product of matrices. 

Given that it's the same as Jacobi formula I've took it for granted that this derivation is possible, but frankly I don't have enough knowledge of differentiation especially on dimensions different from $R^n$.

Comment: The Jacobian and the derivative/differential are basically the same thing. But to express the derivative in terms of the Jacobian matrix, you need to identify the $n \times n$ matrices with elements of $\mathbf{R}^{n^2}$ (by putting all elements in one single long vector, in some order), so that you view the determinant as a map $\det \colon \mathbf{R}^{n^2} \to \mathbf{R}$. Then the Jacobian matrix has size $1 \times n^2$, i.e., a single long row, containing all the partial derivatives $(-1)^{i+j} C_{ij}$ (in the suitable order).